# How to Add table content to combobox?

Tags: c#, sql

This is what I have right now, this code is Just Adding the table name into the Combobox not the customerID. Let say CustomerID has 1,2,3,4,5 I want to be able to add each ID into the combobox
how would I do this?

What I have right now:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds = new DataSet();
    dc = new DataService();
    ds.Tables.Add(dc.GetData("Select * from Customers", "CustomerID"));

    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {

        // do what you want here
          this.comboBox1.Items.Add(item["CustomerID"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ds = new DataSet();
  dc = new DataService();
  DataTable td = dc.GetData("Select * from Customers", "CustomerID");
  foreach (DataRow dr in td.Rows)
  {
    this.comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["CustomerID"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
```

With:

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
```